Unable to fully translate the provided .ts file using C#?
In this official document (at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/mysql/Oracle/README.md), it is mentioned that:
You can find a TypeScript implementation of both classes in the TypeScript/ folder, which should be easy to port over to different runtime languages.

But I cannot convert it into valid C# code, Mainly because the following code cannot be translated correctly:
protected emitDot(): void {
        this.pendingTokens.push(this.tokenFactory.create([this, this.inputStream], MySQLLexer.DOT_SYMBOL,
            this.text, this.channel, this.tokenStartCharIndex, this.tokenStartCharIndex, this.line,
            this.column,
        ));

        ++this.column;
        ++this.tokenStartCharIndex;
    }

The key point is that the tokenStartCharIndex variable is a private member of the Lexer base class during C# runtime (Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.13.1) and cannot be directly modified in subclasses. Is there any solution to this problem?
Is this an issue with Antlr4.Runtime.Standard, or is there any way to bypass it?

This may be a problem, but may not be of practical importance because the fields to the CommonToken can be updated after creating the token. See this port. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78564054/4779853 https://github.com/kaby76/MySqlParser The line "... which should be easy to port over to different runtime languages" is simply not true! I have spent years writing and maintaining ports in grammars-v4, and it is never easy. This grammar is problematic because I would normally rewrite this in "Target Agnostic Format", but it is official Oracle code, so I am resisting modifying it.

@kaby76 Does this statement mean that there is no problem with not updating the value of '_tokenStartCharIndex' in the 'emitDot' interface? Or at what time do I need to update the Token again? The two .ts files attached by the official website do not contain much content, do you mean that even if I translate these two files into C# code, there will still be many hidden issues in the later SQL parsing?

You don't necessarily need to have valid start/end char indices (nor text, as with the TypeScript/Antlr4ng code) for the DOT_SYMBOL for the parse to work. But, as Mike says, there are many solutions. I think a more target-portable way to fix the grammar (without changing the runtime) would be to mark DOT_IDENTIFIER as "skip", have emitDot() enqueue both DOT_SYMBOL and IDENTIFIER, and remove the override for TokenStartCharIndex. I updated the code to reflect this, and it works perfectly fine. https://github.com/kaby76/MySqlParser

The C# runtime does not support multi token handling as it is currently. Most properties have getters and setters, but the TokenStartIndex in Lexer.cs has not.
The Oracle MySQL grammar uses multiple tokens in one place, for DOT_IDENTIFIER, which is a single lexer rule that produces two tokens (a dot and an identifier), which is required for handling of keywords after a dot (which means that keywords that directly follow a period/dot don't need to be quoted and are handled as simple identifiers).
You have now a few options:

Change the C# runtime to allow setting the token start index (add a setter in Lexer.cs).
Disable/remove the DOT_IDENTIFIER rule and remove the MySQLBaseLexer.emitDot method. This will remove handling for this special case mentioned above (but might be acceptable for you).
Remove the action in DOT_IDENTIFIER and let it use the type IDENTIFIER (and remove emitDot()). The token text will then include the dot char and you will have to add special processing for that.
Remove both, the action and the type assignment from the DOT_IDENTIFIER rule and use this special type instead (and remove emitDot()). This would require to change some parser rules that expect DOT IDENTIFIER to also accept DOT_IDENTIIFER. The difference between these two is that the first allows whitespaces between the dot and the identifier, but does not allow keywords instead of a simple identifier. The second version acts in the opposite way.

The last approach was used before I started with the multi token approach, which I think is a bit cleaner (there's no need to think about that special dot-keyword aspect) at the cost of a slightly more complex base lexer.
